# How to convert specific HTML Table with specific columns/values to Excel using JavaScript and Puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, html-table, puppeteer, converters

I am making a web project with **puppeteer**.

In one of the pages of the website I am running (i don't own it), **out of 12 tables**, there is a HTML table inside a table, that inside the `tbody` and `tr`, there are two `td` elements. No classes and no IDs.

**The first `td` is always the column and the second one is the value**.
How can I convert this specific table into a line on an **Excel spreadsheet or a .csv with JavaScript and Puppeteer**?

Dave's answer below only works if you have the page's HTML and if the **content.** works, which is not working for me, even in an example.

Here is the table I am trying to convert. The real one has 29 columns.

```html
<table style="color:Black;background-color:LightGrey;height:400px;width:898px;border: 1px solid grey">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <table>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Column1</td>
                                <td>Value1</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Column2</td>
                                <td>Value2</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Column3</td>
                                <td>Value3</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

The .csv output should be:

```
Column1,Column2,Column3
Value1,Value2,Value3
```

Comment: if someone can find a better title, i'll be glad

Comment: perhaps you could add to show what the desired csv would look like. Would `Column1, Value1` be the first row, and `Column2, Value2` be the second tow and so on? The table looks like it would render with all the "Column" entries in a single column so it's a little confusing at present.

Comment: Do you need to use puppeteer? (Is the table not visible when you "view source?" Do you need need to click a button?..., etc) It may be simpler to just fetch the HTML text and process it with https://cheerio.js.org/ (cheerio is much faster than a headless browser, too!) Puppeteer also has an API to select elements using [CSS selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors).

Comment: @Leftium yes, i need to use puppeteer. I don't own the website, so no buttons. I am gonna check cheerio but i am gonna try the `page.evaluate` that puppeteer has.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This solution has been tested on your sample HTML page.** You will have to craft the CSS selector to be specific enough on the actual page. And/or filter the resulting `elementHandles`:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://renatocfrancisco.github.io/getTableWithPuppeteer/');

  // Get array of elementHandles from page matching this CSS selector.
  const elements = await page.$$('table table td');

  const columns = [];
  const values  = [];

  // Process the elementHandles.
  let i = 0;
  for (const element of elements) {
    // Extract text from elementHandle.
    const text = await element.evaluate(el => el.textContent);
    if ((i++ % 2) == 0) {
        // Even elements are columns.
        columns.push(text);
    } else {
        // Odd elements are values.
        values.push(text);
    }
  };

  // Construct CSV string.
  console.log(`${columns.join(',')}\n${values.join(',')}`);

  await browser.close();
})();
```

**Output:**

```
$ node ./src/index.js 
column1,column2,column3
value1,value2,value3
```

---

**update:**

This is a variation that doesn't use Puppeteer; only [fetch](https://github.com/node-fetch/node-fetch) and [Cheerio.js](https://cheerio.js.org/). It is much faster and uses less resources, so I recommend using this version when possible. (Your sample URL can be processed fine without Puppeteer.)

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

(async () => {
  const fetch = (...args) => import('node-fetch').then(({default: fetch}) => fetch(...args));
  const response = await fetch('https://renatocfrancisco.github.io/getTableWithPuppeteer/');
  const html = await response.text();
  const $ = cheerio.load(html);

  // Get array of elements from page matching this CSS selector.
  const elements = $('table table td');

  const columns = [];
  const values  = [];

  // Process the elementHandles.
  let i = 0;
  for (const element of elements) {
    // Extract text from elementHandle.
    const text = $(element).text();
    if ((i++ % 2) == 0) {
        // Even elements are columns.
        columns.push(text);
    } else {
        // Odd elements are values.
        values.push(text);
    }
  };

  // Construct CSV string.
  console.log(`${columns.join(',')}\n${values.join(',')}`);
})();
```

**Output:**

```
$ node ./src/index.js 
column1,column2,column3
value1,value2,value3
```

Comment: @RenatoC.Francisco I added an alternate solution that doesn't need Puppeteer; just fetch and cheerio.js. Make sure you really need to use Puppeteer!

Comment: thank you so much. it really helped me. now i just need to export this as an .csv. In the real table, there was another table above it with an id that i did not seen it. So i just changed the selector for `page.$$("#id table table id")`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is a little cumbersome as I have broken down the steps to illustrate what we are doing. It could be simplified greatly if the relevant `tbody` had an ID so we could make a direct reference to it using `getElementById` but instead we have to navigate the DOM tree (the relevant table is inside a cell of an outer table).

Having made a reference to a collection of relevant table rows, we can loop though them to extract the data needed. The loops build a comma-separated string for each (output) row, storing them in an array. The array is later joined into lines to give csv output.

This could undoubtedly be simplified but it works. Snippet:

```js
const innerTable = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[1];

const tableBody = innerTable.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];

const tableRows = tableBody.children;

let csv = [];

for (let row=0; row<tableRows.length; row++) { 
  const cells = tableRows[row].children;
    for (let cell=0; cell<cells.length; cell++) {
      if (csv[cell]) {csv[cell] += `,${cells[cell].innerText}`;}
      else {csv[cell] = `${cells[cell].innerText}`;}
      
    } // next cell;
    
} // next row;

csvString = csv.join("\n");
console.log(csvString);
```

```html
<table style="color:Black;background-color:LightGrey;height:400px;width:898px;border: 1px solid grey">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <table>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Column1</td>
                                <td>Value1</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Column2</td>
                                <td>Value2</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Column3</td>
                                <td>Value3</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: i'll not accept this as an answer because it does not solve my problem. i am running puppeteer into a website that is not mine. I am sorry for not being clear.

Comment: @RenatoC.Francisco This answer seems to work. The only part missing is how to "inject" the JS into the puppeteer browser. You can use [`page.evaluate()`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args) to run JS in the page context.

Comment: @Leftium do you know how to get the page's document with puppeteer?

Comment: @RenatoC.Francisco Yes, I have a lot of experience scraping web pages. Both with headless browsers (puppeteer/playwright/phantombuster, etc) and with plain cheerio.js. It would help if you shared a hosted sample of the page you are trying to scrape.

Comment: @Leftium https://renatocfrancisco.github.io/getTableWithPuppeteer/

Comment: @RenatoC.Francisco if I load your github link and paste my answer snippet code into the console, I get the csv exactly as my output.

Comment: @DavePritlove i was looking for an answer using puppeteer.

Comment: puppeteer shmuppeteer, if the URL is live, JS will extract the data. The acceptaed answer is ludicrously unneccesarry but to each their own. Incidentally, if your final goal is to simply get the data into Google Sheets, you could simply have used `ImportHtml` on the live URL and `Transpose` to correct the column/row formatting.